# how to add a parameter to a part "from" into sql query in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I use postgreSQL/pentaho CDE. I need to transmit parameter as schema prefix in my query. I need to run this query: `select * from peredelkino_public.protocol`

I used custom parameter in Pentaho (named 'selector_par'), in properties named 'Javascript code' i wrote 'peredelkino_public.protocol'. 
Then I changed sql query in component 'sql over sqlJndi' like this: `select * FROM (${selector_par})` 
But this query doesn't work! I get message 'Error processing component'. How I can transmit schema prefix in my query?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Replace variables in script`.

Note: if the parameter `selector_par` does not exists or is misspelled, you may get a hard to understand error message.

Comment: His question is about CDE, your answer is valid only in PDI.

Comment: @nsousa : you can use the PDI as data input for the CDE. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, but pretty sure that’s not what he’s doing here, he’s using a standard sql datasource directly in CDE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

CDE can only use JDBC parameters and those cannot be used in the from clause.

If you absolutely need to do that, you should use a Kettle datasource in CDE, as PDI allows any variable to be used in any part of a SQL query.

But make sure you sanitize your inputs. Variable replacements such as that one are a gold mine for hackers.